# Type of storage for emails

Tags: email, server, storage

I have a very simple question. When companies use on premises email servers for their email storage requirements, **what type of storage system is generally used  to store emails?**

Regards
Mavin

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This website is about programming questions only, so your question is off-topic here. That said, emails are just files, so go with any storage you use anyway. If the file system becomes a bottleneck, you can still upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure - I work for NetApp a vendor of storage systems often used for these purposes. I have tried to keep this answer as technology neutral as I can while still staying within my area of subject matter expertise.

Most Email servers on company servers fall into two categories ..

**Unix based systems**, typically fairly small. These often live on the same local disk as the web server and resides on an solid state storage. In most of the implementations I've seen recently for these, are hosted on some form of service provider infrastructure.

In the olden days large Unix based email systems were the norm, I used to install what were considered at the time to be large NFS filers to service these requirements, and Unix/Linux based email systems would create very large high density filesystems with one file per message and would often stretch the capabilities of the both the memory of the storage controller and the spindles that hosted the data. If I were to size one of these today, I would probably use large capacity SSDs on an entry level all flash array which had the capability of moving cold data to an object store.

**Microsoft Exchange based systems**, these are typically fairly large, and back in the olden days, these too used to stress some of the largest storage arrays available but for different reasons. About the same time that everyone started using gmail, microsoft dramatically changed how they did I/O from their exchange databases so that commodity large capacity magnetic SATA disks in a "Direct Attached Storage" configuration could be used. The current description and reccomendations from microsoft for this can be found here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/deployment-ref/storage-configuration?view=exchserver-2019

Some companies still opt to use shared storage infrastructures instead of DAS, the reasons for this are varied and includes company standards, easier support for virtualised servers, storage efficiency techniques such as deduplication, and data services such as snapshot backups. An example of one of these kinds of SAN based configurations from the company I work for can be found here https://www.netapp.com/pdf.html?item=/media/12398-tr-4681pdf.pdf . It is worth noting under the performance section of that document that the use of SATA is still thought of as being ideal up to the 1000 user mark after which a modicum of flash is recommended for caching.